# Java: Custom Icon Issue

Tags: java, swing, class, jframe

I am trying to get a custom icon onto my `JFrame`.  I have the icon image in my project folder but I can not seem to get it to work.

I have also tried `setIconImage(new ImageIcon(imgURL).getImage());` but it does not seem to work for me either.

Also, what is the typical dimensions for a custom icon

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
* @author Curtis
*/
public class Favorites extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
String[] styles = {"Big Band", "Country", "Pop", "Rock", "Rap"};
Font boxFont = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14);
JLabel instruct = new JLabel("What is your favorite type of music?");
JComboBox music = new JComboBox(styles);
JTextField result = new JTextField(20);
final int WIDTH = 270;
final int HEIGHT = 125;

public Favorites()
{
    super("Favorite Music");
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    instruct.setFont(boxFont);
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    add(instruct);
    add(music);
    add(result);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    music.addActionListener(this);
    Image icon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("icnnote.jpg");
    setIconImage(icon);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to move the `setIconImage()` above the `setVisible()`. It displays the frame at the time `setVisible()` is called.

**UPDATE:** You also need to change your image to

`getToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("iccnote.jpg"))`

Comment: is your "icnnote.jpg" file located in the same directory as your class files?

Comment: I changed the order of the code but it still does not seem to be working.        Image icon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("icnnote.jpg");
        setIconImage(icon);
        setVisible(true);

Comment: Yes it is in the the folder as my .java files

Comment: make sure to give the full path if icnnote.jpg is located in a seperate folder.

Comment: Change from `"iccnote.jpg"` to `getClass().getResource("iccnote.png")`

Comment: Nope.  the frame doesn't come up now.

Comment: The image file should probably be in the same folder as the *compiled* files, not the source code. Assuming those are different locations. It's looking for a relative path.

Comment: That's probably because I put apple.png in my above example and it threw an exception. Check your console. I literally just compiled and ran code just like yours.

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks for working with me and sticking through it.  works great now.  the problem was I was using the .png on that last try instead of the .gif  Thanks again!!